# loop for several subjects with multiple do

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to write a bash for loop commands to analyze data of 40 subjects but I face two problems. The loop has multiple variables, e.g.,
PART="af fat ifof ilf mdlf slf2 slf3 tp uf"
SIDE="L R"

The first problem is that after command 1 for subject 1 finishes, it jumps to command 2 for the same subject. I want it to finish the first loop for all 40 subjects before moving to the second loop.
What happens is something like this:

```
Command one -subject 1
Command two -subject 1 
Command n -subject 1
Command 2 -subject 1
.
.
.
```

What I am trying to execute is like this

```
Command one -subject 1
Command one -subject 2
Command one -subject n
Command two -subject 1
Command two -subject 2
Command two -subject n
.
.
.
```

The second problem is, some of these commands have a repetitive option where I can enter repetitively the whole subjects in the same command, the aim is to concatnate the data into one. When I tried to do a for loop I saw the command executed the same number of the subjects!
The command structure is something like this

```
$Command_main Output_file -Input_option Input_1 Input_2 ... Input_n
```

Hope I explained my problem and may I ask your advice.
Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you just need to swap the order of your nested loops. The outer loop should be the command, the inner loop should be the subject.

Comment: You need to post your code, it's impossible to tell what you're doing wrong from this.

Comment: It's also not clear how the variables `PART` and `SIDE` are related to the commands you show.

Comment: Sorry, It seems I wasn't clear enough. An example of code is `for i in $SUBJECT; do for h in $SIDES; do for j in $PARTS; do wb_command \
    -cifti-parcellate \
    ~/${i}.${h}.${j}.Map.dscalar.nii \
    ~/color.dlabel.nii \
    COLUMN \
    $RESULTS/ALL.Map.pscalar.nii \`

Comment: Put the code in the question, not a comment, so you can format it readably.

Comment: Whichever part you want to change slowest should be the outer loop. The part that should change fastest should be the inner loop.